# Stop specific instance to register Eureka

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have a eureka server running on test server and multiple services registers from test server to this eureka server.

Now problem is sometimes developers also connect their local microservice instance for some service to eureka. Due to this it shows multiple instances for that service on eureka and load balancer starts sending request to local servers as well from feign client. That causes issues in testing as test server is not able to connect local developers machine in feign client calls.

I instructed developers to set eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false from local but still if someone connects how can I stop that. Is there a way that eureka server registers only from specific IP (test server ip)? Or any other solution to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the services that you don;t want them to register, remove @EnableDiscoveryClient from the services. @EnableDiscoveryClien lives in spring-cloud-commons and picks the implementation on the classpath. This will stop your services from getting discovered but then you won;t be able to make the Feign calls to other services and take the benefit of load balancing your calls.

Comment: Thanks but problem is there are multiple services. Developers instead running them on local connect test servers service. So they run dev profile of that service from local and same git branch as of test server. We can't remove discoveryclient annotation as that service should be discoverable by zuul on test server.

Comment: @Neeraj Lets try this considering you are maintaining the profiles

@ Profile("!development")
@ Configuration
@ EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ClientConfig {
}
 
Meaning the current configuration file and @ EnableDiscoveryClient within will be loaded in every profile except "developement".